# Slicing array and count

Tags: php, arrays

How can I count the parts of array? For example:

Array:

```
[name] => Michael
[surname] => Hadfield
[midname] => Olsow
[email] => mh@mail.com
[phone] => 3342020
```

I want to count array fields excluding [midname] and [phone]
so the result should be 3

And also I want to create array from this array with result:

```
[name] => Michael
[surname] => Hadfield
[email] => mh@mail.com
```

Is it possible?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$keys_to_exclude = array( 'midname', 'phone');
$new_array = array_diff_key( $original_array, array_flip( $keys_to_exclude));
echo count( $new_array);
print_r( $new_array);
```

With this input array:

```
$original_array = array( 
    'name' => 'Michael',
    'surname' => 'Hadfield',
    'midname' => 'Olsow',
    'email' => 'mh@mail.com',
    'phone' => 3342020
);
```

You should get [your desired output](http://viper-7.com/hdfSoF), that is, the `echo count();` prints `3` and the resulting `$new_array` is:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Michael
    [surname] => Hadfield
    [email] => mh@mail.com
)
```

Comment: It gives me an error:

Warning (2): array_combine() [function.array-combine]: Both parameters should have an equal number of elements [APP/Controller/UsersController.php, line 98]
Warning (2): array_diff_key() [function.array-diff-key]: Argument #2 is not an array [APP/Controller/UsersController.php, line 99]
/app/Controller/UsersController.php (line 100)
null

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a loop to counts the part you do want
2. Multiply the result of `count($array)` by .6 (assuming there is always five parts and three that you want to count)

   `$count = count($array) * .6;`

Comment: But in that case it will count that field too. I need to exclude them.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can always copy the array, unset the 2 indices, and then count it:

```
$array_copy = $array;
unset($array_copy('midname')); // Note unsetting a non-existent key does NOT throw an error.
unset($array_copy('phone'));
echo count($array_copy);
```